# Objective-C malloc with c array of array

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have as property in a view, an array of array like this:

```
@interface MyView : UIView

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint **matrix;

@end
```

in the controller that own this view I have load the data in the -viewDidLoad and free memory in the -viewDidUnload like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    self.myView.matrix = malloc(sizeof(CGPoint*) * array1Size);
    for (int k = 0; k < array1Size; k++) {
        self.myView.matrix[k] = malloc(sizeof(CGPoint) * innerArraySize);
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    for (int k = 0; k < array1Size; k++) {
        free(self.myView.matrix[k]);
        self.myView.matrix[k] = nil;
    }
    free(self.myView.matrix);
    self.myView.matrix = nil;
    [self setMyView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

While profiling I see a leak here. Can someone help me where I'm wrong?

thanks

**update**:

i try to remove free code from viewDidUnload and use dealloc like this:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [self freeArray];
}

- (void) freeArray {

    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        free(self.myView.matrix[k]);
        self.myView.matrix[k] = NULL;
    }

    free(self.myView.matrix);
    self.myView.matrix = NULL;
}
```

then I embed init code in:

```
if (self.graphView.matrix == NULL) {
    ...
}
```

now no more leak, THANKS!

Comment: Your code looks good (apart from assigning `nil` instead of `NULL`, bot that's pretty much the same thing). You can skip the assignment inside the loop, because the array is about to be deallocated. Are you sure that your `viewDidUnload` is being called?

Comment: `-viewDidUnload` is deprecated and you shouldn't use it. You need to move this code to your `-dealloc` method. Also, `-viewDidUnload` only gets called in certain memory pressure situations when the view is completely occluded by another view controller's view. It's not called when the view controller is simply released. Although autoboxing is annoying, it may be easier to just use Foundation collections instead of pointers.

Comment: I can't use dealloc cause i'm using ARC for memory management. Thanks

Comment: @JasonCoco `viewDidUnload` *might be deprecated* if a future iOS version that is still under NDA would abandon view unloading.

Comment: It's perfectly valid and common to use `dealloc` under ARC.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe They've said publicly on the non-beta boards not to use `-viewDidUnload` anymore specifically so that people would stop using it sooner rather than later and to explain that it's deprecated because it leads to the very confusion that this question illustrates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not make sure that each setup of the matrix is matched by exactly one tear down. For example, `viewDidUnload` is not guaranteed to be called. Also, you have no guards against duplicate setup or tear down.

If you really need the C array of arrays, a better approach would be to create it in the initializer of the view (`initWithFrame:` or `initWithCoder:`) and remove it in its `dealloc`.

**Edit:** To alleviate your concerns regarding `dealloc` and ARC:

You can certainly override dealloc in ARC and rely on it being called. The only difference is that you cannot *explicitly* call the overridden implementation (`[super dealloc]`). ARC will insert that for you.

Comment: I can't use dealloc cause i'm using ARC for memory management. And i'd like to use array of struct for performance. May be i've to found a better place where dealloc item? Thanks

Comment: I would also suggest using an array of CGPoint structures directly to avoid all that extra malloc/free traffic.  It'll also occupy less memory and be faster overall for use (a two-float struct is faster than passing a reference to a two float struct and then accessing the contents through indirection).

Comment: You can certainly use `dealloc` in ARC!  It will be called exactly because non-ARC managed resources need to be released.

Comment: i try to use dealloc, but while profiling leak still remain. Can you send me an example of what you mean for "using array of CGPoint directly" ?

Comment: @Guaido79 You should definitely make sure that `(self.myView.matrix == NULL) before initializing the property.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of CGPoint:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint *matrix;

.... init ...
{
   ...
   matrix = (CGPoint*) malloc(arraySize * sizeof(CGPoint));
 ...
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    free(matrix);
}
```

Then you simply set/get CGPoint structures directly in the array:

```
CGPoint someCGPoint = {0,0};
matrix[i] = someCGPoint;

someCGPoint = matrix[i];
```

That'll be faster and more memory efficient than CGPoint**.   And your leak is gone.